# Slider does not update graphic until SetterBar is changed

Tags: graphics, manipulate, slider

I'm illustrating how $sin$ changes when passing different functions to it. For simplicity I'll leave out the $sin$ here.

I created a `Slider` for a parameter and a `SetterBar` for the functions:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[f@x, {x, 0, 5}],
 {p, 1, 10, 1},
 {{f, # &}, {p # &, p #^2 &, #^p &, Sin}, SetterBar},
 ContinuousAction -> True
 ]
```

Problem is, changing `p` does not update the graphic until the `SetterBar` is switched. I tried forcing `ContinuousAction -> True` but it didn't work.

[image: Manipulate]

I'm also curious why I have to explicitly specify `SetterBar` when defining `f`. Unless I do, I get a slider (with the only 3 possible values).
If I remove `p` then it displays as `SetterBar` by default.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just put `p;` before `Plot` so that `Manipulate` knows it should track this symbol too.

Comment: That worked.. but is it documented anywhere? I've never before found such solution.

Comment: This is what 5th example in Manipulate/PossibleIssues more or less shows. Though what it shows is really a combination of what we have here and a scoping of  `a` issue. On the other hand in Manipulate/Details&Options there is one bullet point: `With the default setting TrackedSymbols->Automatic, only symbols that appear explicitly in expr are tracked.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kuba nailed the origin of your problem in [his comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136494/slider-does-not-update-graphic-until-setterbar-is-changed#comment368248_136494): in your code `Manipulate` is not aware that it needs to track symbol `p` because it does not appear explicitly in the expression to be manipulated.

Kuba's workaround that adds `p` explicitly to the manipulated expression works well of course. However, I'll also mention that you can add any of the following [`TrackedSymbols`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackedSymbols.html) directives to your `Manipulate` to make it track the symbol `p` that otherwise does not appear in the manipulated expression.

- `TrackedSymbols -> True` is the most direct solution: it forces tracking of symbols that appear in the `Manipulate` controls.
- You can also list the symbols to track explicitly: `TrackedSymbols :> {f, p}`.
- `TrackedSymbols -> All` is the most draconian solution, in that it tracks all possible symbols.

These use cases are documented in the "Details" section of the [docs for `TrackedSymbols`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackedSymbols.html); any one of these would work for you.